# How to overlay images with css (cross-browser)

Tags: html, css

The best solution is definitely use multiple background image, unfortunately IE9

```
<a style="background: url('image1.png');" href="page.php"><img src="image2.png"/></a>
```

Unfortunately it does not work properly. How can overlay the two images and maybe image1.png position at the bottom left of image2.png?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple solution is to use position absolute and position relative in CSS.
The first step is to define a container and apply `position:relative`, in such way all the inner elements that have `position:absolute` will refer to the coordinates of the container.
Then we can set both images on `position:absolute; top:0; left:0;` and we can manually decide which one to send to the background using `z-index`. In summary:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="image background"><img src="" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="image"><img src="" alt="" /></div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
/* CSS */
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 5;
}

.image.background {
  z-index: 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it,

--> set the `position` of `<a>` to relative

--> display `<a>` as `inline-block`

--> explicitly mention the `background-size` and set the dimension of `<a>` to size of the  `background-image` **! IMPORTANT !**

--> now absolutely position `<img>` to `bottom: 0px` and `left: 0px`, don't forget to specify the dimension of `<img>` element **! IMPORTANT !**

here is a typical HTML and CSS (i have used sample image) --> [JSfiddle View](http://jsfiddle.net/Qj67E/)

HTML

```
<a id="id1" href="page.php">
    <img id="id2" src="http://www.wiljoaskesmontage.nl/rw_common/images/logo_small.jpg"/>
</a>
```

CSS

```
#id1
{
    background-image: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/26/Ayyavazh_logo_small.PNG');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left-bottom;
    background-size: 100px 100px;
    height:100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#id2
{
    width:30px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**edit :** by default `background-image` will be in background and `<img>` will be in foreground, use `z-index` to specify the order of display, element with highest `z-index` will be displayed first